# SAML 2.0 Request to AD FS

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

I am submitting a SAMLRequest from an HTML form to ADFS. Upon sending the request, I got a form that asks for Username and Password. When I give valid Username and Password and submit the form, it prompts me with the following error:

```
There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.
If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and 
provide the reference number to identify the problem.
**Reference number**: 5881826a-80a1-4e00-8baa-c477c2348ef1
```

Here is SAMLRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest
  AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://www.someurl.com"
  ForceAuthn="false" IsPassive="false"
  IssueInstant="2015-04-09T11:17:43.273Z"
  ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
  Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sts.abc.com/adfs</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ds saml samlp" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:Transform>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>eOh4k4OqoVnNCoCMpKTgqILoLGw=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
IvxweY9qkKKy5FrhHn08S2Q0KFeBR26t7N5/nbUXJEyVRpK8UopEnYT361pq5udgTaw3OMpoTIGg
bNLzSVYu91q12XOPTXyyx2UP6yfDq3lgD+5w71t6ziNTXgQuFhr8a2G97p83xOLF5f3l8MrGSjpL
Y7tVBKESAGw+klqVjotM1p5QvB51YVhNkvAy5Fw2jvZVTmjahRg/4wjDplbU1rdHiZ4mumyh5NZT
BwNCx/003ba7jaKEjTze0UG1wb4qtI63P1/7hqWVLGHrArG46Q2qPpiwBNCOpxOlgXOeU/mfOjQG
hMcDv5+3AllzdlrPoQE90WItScPG4yzu8eiYSQ==
</ds:SignatureValue>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/>
  <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
  </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Here is the Stack Trace I got from ADFS Event Log:

```
    Log Name:      AD FS 2.0/Admin
    Source:        AD FS 2.0
    Date:          4/7/2015 10:36:41 AM
    Event ID:      364
    Task Category: None
    Level:         Error
    Keywords:      AD FS
    User:          LTI\sa-adfs
    Computer:      SOMESERVER.ADMIN.LES.LOCAL
    Description:
    Encountered error during federation passive request. 

    Additional Data 

    Exception details: 
    Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClientManager.ProcessRequest(Message request)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest(MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest[T](MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.CreateErrorMessage(HttpSamlMessage httpSamlMessage, SamlStatus status)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSamlError(SamlStatus status)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSamlError(SamlStatus status)

    System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClientManager.ProcessRequest(Message request)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest(MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest[T](MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.CreateErrorMessage(HttpSamlMessage httpSamlMessage, SamlStatus status)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSamlError(SamlStatus status)


    Event Xml:
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
    <Provider Name="AD FS 2.0" Guid="{20E25DDB-09E5-404B-8A56-EDAE2F12EE81}"   />
    <EventID>364</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-07T14:36:41.375618200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7999</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{4501AAAF-E56D-4553-A6C9-27AC5190A0EA}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="4956" ThreadID="2756" />
    <Channel>AD FS 2.0/Admin</Channel>
    <Computer>250ADFS1.ADMIN.LES.LOCAL</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2101114347-22087826-926709054-84784" /> 
     </System>
   <UserData>
    <Event xmlns:auto-ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ActiveDirectoryFederationServices/2.0/Events">
      <EventData>
        <Data>Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClientManager.ProcessRequest(Message request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest(MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest[T](MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.CreateErrorMessage(HttpSamlMessage httpSamlMessage, SamlStatus status)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSamlError(SamlStatus status)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSamlError(SamlStatus status)

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClientManager.ProcessRequest(Message request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest(MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest[T](MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.CreateErrorMessage(HttpSamlMessage httpSamlMessage, SamlStatus status)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSamlError(SamlStatus status)

</Data>
      </EventData>
    </Event>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

Is this error due to something missing in SAMLRequest, or It is the ADFS side issue. How to track down this issue and what can be possible reasons that cause this error.

Comment: Is it the only error entry you found in the event log? Usually there might be another one which tells what the exact error is. Besides, does ADFS' tracing log have anything interesting?

Comment: Many things are wrong with the SAML request. Push it through a validating parser first.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the request was asking for a Transient NameId. You can check if Relying party trust for that SP has a NameId claim rule to issue a correct one as described in http://blog.auth360.net/2012/09/02/adfs-as-an-identity-provider-and-saml-2-0-saas-application-integration/